# Matching multi-line parenthesis in R syntax with vim

Tags: vim

In the following R code vim highlights the closing parenthesis in red, indicating that it can't find the matching opening parenthesis. If I unindent the third line this is no longer the case.

```
if(TRUE) {
    x = c(
    )
}
```

What is going on here? How do I fix this?

Comment: What is inside your collection? empty?

Comment: What do you mean by collection?